# oc4j enterprise manager console session timeout?

Tags: java, oc4j

How can I change the session timeout for the OC4J Enterprise Manager console?
It times out too quickly between deployments in our development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The default session timeout of an application in OC4J is 20 minutes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28959/sessions.htm#sthref110). If you need to change the same for an application, you have to explicitly set the session timeout value in web.xml.

This holds good even for Enterprise Manager as well, which is deployed as the application *ascontrol*. The web.xml file of *ascontrol* will be available at $ORACLE_HOME/j2ee/OC4J_INSTANCE/config/applications/ascontrol/ascontrol/WEB-INF/web.xml. You will have to introduce the session-timeout element in this file at the appropriate location (usually at the end), so that the XML is valid. A restart of the OC4J instance is required.

Do note that, this comes with no guarantees, and it is better to confirm via Oracle Support if this configuration change is supported.

Alternatively, you can use [admin_client.jar](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28950/adminclient.htm#BABCCJEC) or [admin.jar](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28950/admincli.htm#BABBDAAJ) to deploy your application.